# WS02 EI scheduled task - how to encrypt parameters

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, wso2-enterprise-integrator

When creating a WS02 scheduled task, I need it to take authentication details for other web services as parameters. I would like to create the job with its configuration encrypted to be sure those details are not being stored as plain text anywhere.

I have turned on cipher encryption for the IE instance.
I have stored an an encryption of the value in cipher-text.properties

> Sample.Password=(long encryption value)

I have referenced the config parameter to use the encrypted value in cipher-tool.properties

> Sample.Password=repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/tasks/SampleTask.xml//task/property[@name='param1'][@value],true

I have run

> ciphertool.bat -Dconfigure

which updated the task xml as follows;

```
<property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="param1" svns:secretAlias="Sample.Password" value="password"/>
```

But the scheduled task picks up 'password' for the value, not the decrypted value stored in cipher-text.properties

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So attempting to encrypt a scheduled task parameter falls under the category of a synapse configuration setting, not a general configuration setting. This means that the encryption alias is to be set in the IE UI under Secure Vault Tool/Manage Passwords. In the configuration xml file, the aliased value is referenced by {wso2:vault-lookup('Sample.Password')}
In theory, putting in <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
             name="param1"
             value="{wso2:vault-lookup('Sample.Password')}"/>
should work.

Comment: But it doesn't work, because the process that performs the alias substitutions doesn't look inside quoted attributes. So it would have worked if the alias was a value stored inside a tag, but it's an attribute, so it doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have to encrypt password in synapse configuration (synapse configurations are used to create the synapse runtime. is different than the way you encrypt passwords in other configuration files (files inside /conf) folder. Refer to our official [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks)for more information.

This [blog](https://medium.com/@sewmijayaweera/step-by-step-guid-to-add-a-scheduled-task-using-wso2-ei-c98649872f0f) explain how to create a scheduled task to trigger a proxy service which logs the actual value of a encrypted password using a given alias.

If you are looking for a solution where you need to resolve an encrypted password (using secure vault) inside a Task you have written, that information can be found from the [blog post](https://medium.com/@sewmijayaweera/how-to-resolve-a-encrypted-password-which-is-used-in-synapse-configuration-inside-a-scheduled-task-b9df871077a4)